# Changing distance units in joined layer in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, vector, spatial-join, proximity

I am performing a Vector analysis using the `'Join attributes by nearest'` tool. I am trying to evaluate the distance between a central highway and each vector point in a layer (which each represent buildings).

The Joined layer shows each of these distances but the unit for distance used is currently degrees. How can I get distances to be shown in metres or kilometres?

Comment: By saving the layer in a CRS which is based on `m`, most likely your local UTM strip.

Comment: using "Reproject layer" or "Warp"

Comment: @BERA is there any significant difference to saving the data to a new file using a different CRS? Kinda curious right now.

Comment: You mean compared to save by right-click - save vector layer as - then choose a projected CRs?